# Why Defining A React Component Constructor the ES6 Way Won't Work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert this:

```
constructor () {
  ...
}
```

To this:

```
constructor = () => {
  ...
}
```

But it won't work. May you please give an explanation as to why is this not allowed? Is it dangerous in any way or was it just an arbitrary choice to not allow a constructor to be non-static?

Comment: Arrow functions are not the same as ordinary functions in some important ways. One of those differences is that `this` is not bound as it is for ordinary functions when called.

Comment: I suppose the question is why you would want to do that.

Comment: Are you using classes ? It that's so, read a bit about constructors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor. They are not like other class property to which you assign a function.

Comment: An `=` is a syntax error in an ES6 `class` body. Not sure what you are trying to achieve anyway with arrow syntax.

Comment: Okay thanks everybody. I am not trying to achieve anything, I was curious to find out why is the constructor not allowed to be non-static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 classes are basically just syntactic sugar around the old ES5 prototypical inheritance. The `constructor` in ES6 is analagous to the function itself in ES5. For example:

```
class foo {
    constructor () {
       console.log('hello world');
    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('hello world');
}
```

The arrow functions in class definitions that you're trying to do aren't yet a part of ecmascript, but thanks to babel's transpiler you can use them today. What babel does is the following:

```
class foo {
   boundFunction = () => {
       console.log('bound');
   }
}
```

becomes:

```
function foo() {
    this.boundFunction = () => {
        console.log('bound');
    }
}
```

Note that babel is taking the function out of the class definition and moving it into the constructor. This way, each time an object is created, it will get its own instance of the function

But then we get to your scenario. What would this be telling babel to do?

```
class foo {
   constructor = () => {
       console.log('bound');
   }
}
```

So from the `boundFunction` example, babel's supposed to move this function *into* the constructor, and yet from the first example it's also supposed to *be* the constructor. These are mutually exclusive things, so babel gives you an error.

Comment: Babel can transpile arrow functions in classes if you set it up for it to do so. The problem is scope. An arrow function doesn't have its own `this`, which means the constructor function is rendered useless because its state is the `window` or `undefined` in React.